# Blackberry browser automatically inserts blue background

Tags: css, browser, blackberry, textbox, background

I need to create a web application to run on Blackberry browser. The issue i am facing is:

There are a few text boxes on various pages which are given a CSS class. I needed to use border property to give them all- 1px solid Black. But on incorporation of this border property for Blackberry, there is an open issue. Once i tap on the edit field, the Blackberry browser is somehow filling the text box with blue background. Note that such behaviour is not seen on iPhone and Android. It seems that Blackberry browser is using its default behaviour. Is there any way to stop the automatic behavior of Blackberry browser such as some css property or javascript or meta tag? Has anyone else faced similar problem?

---

On More research into this, i found that the border is not actually making the background as blue. But, as soon as we include border property, it highlights that element with its default blue color. (Likewise, it does in case of taps on images). I tied using -webkit-tap-highlight-color property to disable it. But, it works on iPhone but not on Blackberry.

Comment: Yes I have a BB Bold 3 and it does it for all the sites AFAIK.

Comment: probably the same as chrome adding a blue bordered highlight to textfields and a yellow background if it was autofilled :) browser defaults, like Ates said

Comment: corroded: i do not see such behaviour of chrome in my application. Though there is some dark yellow color border automatically created for chrome but not background. Although, i dont have to worry much about desktop browsers as its scope is for mobile browsers.:)

Comment: More research lead me to css property "outline:none" Outline property was leading to the highlight of any element. The issue is solved as soon as you do the outline:none  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More research lead me to css property "outline:none" Outline property was leading to the highlight of any element. The issue is solved as soon as you do the outline:none

Answer (score 0):

You're better off not overriding the default behaviour of the browser. Blackberry users will likely be accustomed to the blue highlight. It is most probably being added with a `:focus` CSS pseudo-class. If you stil want to override it, you could add a `input:focus { background: #fff; }` etc. rule.

Comment: thanks Ates for your reply. After reviewing it again, i realized that i had already tried this in my code. But still, Blackberry was doing the same behavior